# How to update metadata of audio file in Android R ( Android 11 ) media store?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore, android-10.0, android-11

I have been trying to update audio file metadata in android's MediaStore.

I'm setting `MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING` to 1 before updating the value. In android 10, it works well but in Android11, metadata update is not wokring even with `IS_PENDING`.

Here is the code that I'm using,

```
val contentValues = ContentValues()

    if (hasQ()) {
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        application.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
    }

    contentValues.clear()

    if (hasQ()) contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    with(editTrackTagInfo) {
        title?.let { it -> contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, it) }
        album?.let { it -> contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, it) }
        artist?.let { it -> contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, it) }
    }

    val rowsUpdated = application.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues,
            null, null)
```

For android 11, rowsUpdated is mostly 0. And at few times it comes out to be 1 but even in that case no metadata is updating.